# "Мучать" или "мучить"?

Tags: орфография, глаголы

Как правильно: "муч**а**ть" или "муч**и**ть"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Правильно: *муч**и**ть.* Форму *муч**а**ть* словарь Кузнецова даёт с пометой *разг.*; таким образом, употребление её вне разговорной сферы нежелательно.

Answer (score 4):

Варианты равноправны и синонимичны.
Похоже, что в современном языке "мучить" несколько вытесняет "мучать", но не уверен.
Кузнецов тут не авторитет. 
Об этих глаголах писал, кажется, еще Аванесов, но не могу сейчас процитировать.

Comment: Я тоже недавно смотрела эти глаголы. Согласна с вашим вариантом ответа. Но не помню, к каким словарям обращалась.